# Follow Up Customer Database Design

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Please excuse me if this isn't the traditional format of how questions are asked or if it is too broad.

I am currently looking for suggestions on how to design and build a customer database with some very simple fields. I work in the sales department for a company that retails after-market truck accessories both online and over the phone. I have some basic programming skills and a little technical ability, the goal of this project is to create a method of targeting sales leads we would like to follow up with.

We will be collecting information from the salesman individually, I imagined creating a web portal that allowed them to answer the following questions:

1. Customer Email?
2. How did they find us?
3. The website they called in on.
4. Year of the Vehicle?
5. Make of the Vehicle?
6. Was the initial investment < $750.00?
7. Date of purchase?

I would like to query and target customers based on those questions I have listed above.

Any suggestions or insight would be very much appreciated. 
-Luke

Comment: What are you actually asking? You want table design for this? Probably for this simple a data capture application you would just have one table, with all these answers as columns, as well as for instance the Sales Person name and date this info was recorded... If you wanted to go further - you could have a table for Vehicle or VechicleMake and reference to that, but it doesn't sound like you even need that

Comment: How would you recommend building a simple data capture application is really what I wanted to know.

Comment: That is far far too broad a question to answer... There are literally endless ways. You tagged mssql, so first read some mysql tutorials: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/ then learn a front end like ASP.Net if you use windows, or node.js or something if you want free, then build your data capture application... i don't really know what you are expecting anyone to tell you, there is no silver bullet, which is why software development companies exist and are so diverse

Comment: If you want a real easy time use something like lightswitch: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff851953.aspx only dont cause it is horrible

Comment: @LukeBarlett Or just use Google Forms: https://www.google.co.uk/forms/about/ It doesn't sound like you even need a database or application for what you have mentioned in your question, you can just dump the form results into a spreadsheet and do the analysis there...

Comment: Or pay me money and i'll do it :P

Comment: @Milney I would be willing to pay someone to coach me on putting this together, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You have to face a three-stage process:

First Step: Collect all the information you need to include in your database. You can collect this information from people or documents.

Second Phase: Develops a relational database model that allows you to manage the information according to the first 3 formalization rules. If the database is used by external users, you should designs queries and forms to facilitate their work.

Third Phase: Make your own database. If you do not have a software yet, look for one that supports the relational model. Have you already tried MS access?